# How to read a record from HBase then store into Spark RDD (Resilient Distributed Datasets); and read one RDD record then write into HBase?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hbase, bigdata

So I want to write a code to read a record from Hadoop HBase then store it into Spark RDD (Resilient Distributed Datasets); and read one RDD record then write into HBase. I have ZERO knowledge about either of the two and I need to use AWS cloud or Hadoop virtual machine. Someone please guide me to start from scratch.

Comment: Please read online documentations and books about AWS and Hadoop. That should be your starting point. Then create some code, play around and then start the big projects. Furthermore you need to provide us code... nobody here will do your work for free.

Comment: @Arjun you need to do some basic analysis and if you have any issues then come back.

Comment: @codedge: I don't want anyone to do my work. If you can read carefully, I asked for guidance to start from scratch. I didn't even know what hadoop or spark is at the first place. If you cannot understand the question, better to keep the comments to yourself.
BTW it took me long to figure out that Cloudera quickstart VM is a good starting point. If someone had told me about this earlier, I wouldn't have wasted hours on the setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please make use of the basic code in Scala where we are reading the data in HBase using Scala. Similarly you can write a table creation to write the data into HBase

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.{HBaseAdmin, Result}
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.{ HBaseConfiguration, HTableDescriptor }
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable

import org.apache.spark._

object HBaseApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("HBaseApp").setMaster("local[2]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
    val tableName = "table1"

    System.setProperty("user.name", "hdfs")
    System.setProperty("HADOOP_USER_NAME", "hdfs")
    conf.set("hbase.master", "localhost:60000")
    conf.setInt("timeout", 100000)
    conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "localhost")
    conf.set("zookeeper.znode.parent", "/hbase-unsecure")
    conf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, tableName)

    val admin = new HBaseAdmin(conf)
    if (!admin.isTableAvailable(tableName)) {
      val tableDesc = new HTableDescriptor(tableName)
      admin.createTable(tableDesc)
    }

    val hBaseRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(conf, classOf[TableInputFormat], classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable], classOf[Result])
    println("Number of Records found : " + hBaseRDD.count())
    sc.stop()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks JustCoder. Can you also tell me the steps to set up Hadoop and Spark or give me some links for the same ?

Comment: @Arjun, Please use these links for setting up the Apache Spark or Hadoop.  [Quora](https://www.quora.com/topic/Apache-Spark). and also [Cloudera](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-3-x/topics/cloudera_quickstart_vm.html)

Comment: This link discussed about sample setup of HBase, Spark and HDFS. https://dzone.com/articles/sample-app-hbase-spark-hdfs

Comment: Thanks a lot @JustCoder

Comment: Please accept it as the answer if it is relevant to what you are expecting.!! Thanks for A2A

Comment: sorry I don't have enough rep to vote for your answer :(

Comment: No Problem!! Hoping this answer assisted in what you are looking for!!

Comment: one more thing. I am using the Cloudera quickstart VM. Do I need to do any specific setting or will this code work on Eclipse ?

Comment: You have to add some libraries to your eclipse and then start developing!!     hadoop-common-2.3.0.jar
hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.0.2-alpha.jar
hadoop-test-1.2.1.jar
  It must be present in 
${HADOOP_HOME}/share/hadoop/mapreduce